# Atmosphere - how to push data from struts 2 action

Tags: java, push, atmosphere

my question is how to push data from server in atmosphere without using javaScript

I followed the chat tutorial it was so understandable, now I want to push data from an action in struts 2 (and not from javascript) i know that I must call  `.onMessage()` method but I'm blocked on how to build `AtmosphereResponse` argument I tried

```
AtmosphereResponse response = new AtmosphereResponse.Builder().build();
```

but it return `NullPointerExeption` when I use `response.write()` methode

thanks a lot for your collaboration

Answer (score 1):

Solution : `BroadcasterFactory.getDefault().lookup("/atmosphere").broadcast(message);`

`"/atmosphere"` is your AtmosphereServlet pattern